# Weather, exchange rates and other feeds

Tags: asp.net, web-services, widget, weather, add-on

I am building a real estates website, I want to include some details on the homepage about the current weather, temperature, humidity, etc. I may also want to include some exchange rates.

It all should be current and up-to-date, I know there are plugins or add-ons I can use which requires me zero-coding. I just don't know what to use.

Any recommendations?

PS: though this might not be relevant, I am using ASP.net 3.5 and VB.net.

And I am looking for weather information on Cyprus (northern Cyprus to be specific)

Comment: Near dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at Yahoo's:
http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/

There are tutorials at http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/ and you might be able to use their finance API for FX

There are a lot more linked in the answer to [this (near duplicate) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507441/best-weather-apis).